# reading arabic data from Oracle database in java

Tags: java, database, oracle, arabic

I want to read data from database. the data is in arabic language. the character set of my database is AL32UTF8.
when i try to retrive the data i get "????"
please do reply how to solve this problem
this is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
String username = "hr";
String password = "hr";
String sql = "SELECT WORDS_URDU FROM FINALLY WHERE DFFGG=430";
Connection connection;
try {
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
//System.out.println(statement.execute(sql));
connection.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
System.err.println(e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to determine is whether the data in the table is stored correctly.  If it is, there's a display problem.

Check if you have set the proper value for `NLS_LANG` environment variable on the client side where the program is running.

Make sure your terminal program that your program is running in is capable of displaying the required characters.

To determine if the database contents are corrupt, you might try doing 'select dump(words_urdu) from finally where dffgg=430;'.  This will show the actual characters that are stored in the database.  If the `NLS_LANG` environment variable was not set correctly at data insertion time, the data may be corrupt in the database.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes the data is stored correctly. i checked it by executing select statement